# setImageBitmap from URL in the main thread

Tags: android

Task:
setImageBitmap from URL into recyclerview items and use PDFBox lib to get PDF file with all recyclerview items including the images in these items.

Problem:
converting url image to bitmap requires not working on main thread and that makes pdf file created without images set to its position (blank in image position).

permitting working on main thread makes it possible for the app to crash or too slow.

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 10;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            url = new URL(imag_path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
```

resulting PDF photo as below:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** to load image from url?

Comment: Either use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) these libraries are better.

Comment: `StrictMode` is not for this purpose its a development tool and you seems to intentionally writing a wrong code with it .. Use any Image Loader API like mentioned in comments above .

Comment: You can also use Fresco library by facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use glide to download the image in the main Thread

```
                         Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load("URL")
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;

                             //YOU GET THE DOWNLOADED BITMAP HERE
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: the bitmap to be set is resource
setImageBitmap(resource)   correct?? but why return false ?

Comment: it worked after adding .submit after closing the listener close parenthesis, but not all the images appears in the PDF file, I don't know why?

Comment: at last it worked I had to generate the file after all recyclerview items have been recycled and scrolled so I put the button beneath the recyclerview ;) anyway thanks @Dyenal Dinesh